# Android Opentok

Tags: android, video-streaming, opentok

I am using OpenTok to call another person, but the other person's call to me is not coming and logcat gives this info:

`Session error: Invalid token. Make sure you're using the latest OpenTok server SDK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably generating an invalid token for the other person. Make sure your server code is passing in the correct parameters to generate tokens: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/server/

Also, to debug your tokens, remove the string 'T1==' from the front of the token and base64 decode it. The decoded string should contain a `sessionId` and `apiKey`.